# Why can't i open pdf file from device storage?

Tags: android, pdf, storage, pdf-viewer

I am saving a pdf file that im am receiving from server via method:

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "order.pdf");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I did manage to save it on the device though as much as i understood i can't open it directly after the download because it's downloading from a item click in a adapter. Anyway, I made it so that after the download it changes the page to another activity where i should be able to open it, though it still fails. Code I am using in the activity:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/order.pdf";

    File file=new File(path);

    if(file.canRead())
    {
        pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                Toast.makeText(PdfActivity.this, String.valueOf(nbPages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).load();

    }
```

Since the code should be correct, I tried a lot of variations of getting the path to the pdf, none seemed to work. Is the issue in the path or is it a whole other problem?

Edit: It can't read the file in `if(file.canRead())`

Comment: You are not printing the stack traces when there is an exception. Or have a log statement there or a toast. So you do not know what is happening. Please adapt your code.

Comment: You should add an outputStream.close(); before that return true;.

Comment: Your finally block will never be executed.

Comment: All of that is fixable, though even with that i still do get the file on my device but cant open it.